# Update Opportunities in MS Dynamics 365 CRM using Zapier

Tags: dynamics-crm, zapier, dynamics-crm-365

I want to perform update functionality to change and add more values in opportunity using Zapier.

Has anyone tried to update MS Dynamics 365 CRM opportunity from zapier?
Since there is no option available in Zapier for this, what would be the way to update it?

I have explored some options and came across API Requests and App Extensions feature offered by MS Dynamics. Is there any other way possible?

Comment: I don't use zapier but it has the connector https://zapier.com/apps/microsoft-dynamics-crm/integration, the alternative is to do a raw http request (and the required authentication) with zapier (but you will need to create the azure app and get the client credentials